# How to change force.com site URL to my company name(www.mycompany.com)

Tags: force.com-sites

I've created a site in salesforce. i.e. force.com site.

Currently my site URL is like this : https://mysandbox-mycompany.cs1.force.com

But after moving this site to production. I want my website name should be my company name like. www.mycompamy.com

I don't want force.com or any other word in website URL . How we can do it.

Please guide.

Comment: Check this URL - [Registering a Custom Domain for Your Force.com Site](http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/registering-a-custom-domain-for-your-force-com-site)

Comment: Also [this](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sites_creating_subdomain.htm&type=0) one.

Answer (score 0):

You can also forward whatever domain you want to the salesforce url. For example, when a user types in www.yourcompany.com it forwards to the salesforce production site automatically. Depending how your domain is set up, this should not be to difficult to do.

Comment: How can i do?  I read the above provided link also, but its not clear to me.